# Use the resulted object by find() to ternary operation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, find, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

There is an array of objects of this form:

```
const rows = [{name: "john", color: "blue", height: 177, weight: 82},
              {name: "anna", color: "red", height: 167, weight: 62},
              {name: "mike", color: "green", height: 181, weight: 78},
              {name: "sue", color: "red", height: 164, weight: 57}];
```

I need to find the first element that satisfies a condition and use it in the ternary, something like:

```
{rows.find(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna") ? ... : ... }
```

Is there a way to get the result from the condition into the middle ternary term? Like:

```
{rows.find(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna") ? a.height * a.width : null }
```

Comment: `find` expects only a true or false value. You don't *change* the element in the callback.

Comment: There is no harm in creating extra variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>There's no one-liner for your example with `color`, `width`, and `height`.</s> *(Actually, there is,¹ but...)* You need to either search again (which will often be just fine, but...) or store the search result in a variable so you can use it twice.

It looks like you're using this in a JSX expression. Typically grab the things you can to locals prior to the expression, then use those locals:

```
const entry = rows.find(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna");
const result = entry ? a.height * a.width : null;
// ...later in your JSX...
{result}
```

Another option if it's a common operation is to (as always) put it in a reusable function:

```
// Somewhere it can be reused:
function areaOfOptionalObject(obj) {
    return obj ? obj.width * obj.height : null;
}
// In your JSX:
{areaOfOptionalObject(rows.find(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna"))}
```

Where you draw the line is a judgement call. For instance, you might put the `find` in the function:

```
// Somewhere it can be reused:
function areaOfMatchingObject(array, predicate) {
    const obj = array.find(predicate);
    return obj ? obj.width * obj.height : null;
}
// In your JSX:
{areaOfMatchingObject(rows, a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna")}
```

---

¹ The one-liner is:

```
{rows.filter(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna").map(a => a.weight * a.height)[0] ?? null}
```

...but it fully traverses `rows` (rather than stopping when it finds something), creates two unnecessary temporary arrays, and is a bit...awkward. Still, it works, and `rows` probably isn't all that big and the temporary arrays aren't really a big deal.

Thanks [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66048262/use-the-resulted-object-by-find-to-ternary-operation/66048431?noredirect=1#comment116776039_66048431) that `filter` -> `map` `[0]` would do it!

Comment: There sort of is a one liner - `filter` -> `map` -> `[0]`. However, it changes the semantics slightly and it isn't much clearer.

Comment: @VLAZ - Ah, you mean `{rows.filter(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna").map(a => a.weight * a.height)[0] ?? null}`? Yeah. Blech. :-) But yup, it's a one-liner!

Comment: Yes, it fullfills the criteria of a oneliner. I'm not sure I'd use it over just making an extra variable or a function.

Comment: @VLAZ - I wouldn't, but I've definitely seen people write code link that inline. Well spotted!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in this way:

```
const found = rows.find(a => a.color === "red" && a.name === "anna");
const res = found ? found.height * found.width : null;
```